# C++ Append character to std::string from int

Tags: c++, string, pointers, scope, append

I've got a character from the keyboard, by integer:

```
int c = getch();
```

an I want to append it to a string only if it isn't a `return`:

```
void somefunction()
{
    std::string str = "you pressed: ";
    int c;
    while ( 1 )
    {
        c = getch();
        if ( c == 10 ) break;
        char* ch;
        sprintf(ch,"%c",c);
        str += std::string(ch);
    }
}
```

however, this creates a segmentation error when the scope of `somefunction` is left. I'm geussing that when the dtor for `str` is called the pointer to `ch` isn't available any more.

How can I remedy this?

Comment: Your problem here is that the pointer ch is not initialized and could point anywhere.

Comment: The segmentation error happens because you don't actually allocate any memory for character array `sprintf` prints to.

Comment: Your other problem is that you are mixing C style string manipulation with C++ style thereof. This can be done, of course, but isn't necessary and non-trivial to get right (as indicated by sstn).

Comment: The segfault is because sprintf is writing into random data. Change `char *ch;` to `char ch[2];` - but really, use any of the proper std::string methods in the answers...

Comment: the strange thing is that when I comment out the `str += ...` line, no segfault occurs, leading me to believe the `ch` initialisation is done properly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are getting segmentation fault, because you are trying to `sprintf` string into unknown (not yet allocated) memory:

```
char* ch;
sprintf(ch,"%c",c);
```

possible fix of your code would be to replace `char* ch;` with `char ch[2];` which would cause `ch` to become an statically allocated array with an automatic storage duration.

But note that since you are programming in C++ it would be wiser to use streams and methods of `std::string` rather than C-style (`char*`) strings and C-style functions like `sprintf`.

Comment: +1. Actually it is a complete answer, as it explains the cause of the segfault.

Answer (score 13):

This is much easier than you think:

```
str.push_back(c);
```

Comment: @Nawaz What makes you say that?

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin: Ohh... I mistakenly thought it as `+` rather than `+=`.

Comment: `stringstream` could be another class of interest here.